# How to merge two rendered .mkv videos from command prompt

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor, error, command-line

So I was trying to use video sequencer to merge videos (I have 10 videos to merge) and I have the code. This code uses the line bpy.context.area.type='SEQUENCER_EDITOR'. When I try to run the code from cmd prompt, I get a NoneType Error. Please suggest how to merge the videos. If any changes make the sequencer work it will be great, or any thing that will merge 10 videos using blender python codes run from command prompt. Please help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "merge"? Do you mean put one video after the other to make a single longer video? You don't need blender for that. You can do it directly in ffmpeg https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Comment: I know it. But it said that ffmpeg is not recognized as internal or external command. Also I need to do it with blender python code. Please help me in that too.

Comment: I agree with @susu, Blender's video sequence editor can't be used as a command line tool, that's what ffmpeg is for, (you might need to install it). What "code" are you referring to? The bit you quote will only work within Blender as an addon.

Comment: You can use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) in Python to call command line argument